# parallel threads + recursive methods

Tags: c#, multithreading, recursion

I have a scenario where user uploads a text file and with the file size I update its current and all parent directories.

I am using asynchronous threads like `Task.Run()` and calling a recursive method to update the current file directory to the top level directory with the uploaded file size.

The problem is when I upload 100 files, and start `Task.Run()` for every file to update its directories, it misses the files. E.g. I uploaded 100 files but only 92 files size were updated by the recursive method.

Firstly I thought it might be an EntityFramework 6 issue; but I replaced it with simple ado.net code and it's still not working 100%.

Here is the code of that recursive method

```
public bool AddToAllSubFolder(SubFolder subFolder, long fileSize, int fileCount, string dbName)
        {
            bool status = false;
            if (subFolder != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(subFolder.FolderName))
            {
                try
                {
                    using (DBContext context = DBContext.CreateInstance(dbName))
                    {
                        context.SubFolders.Where(d => d.SubFolderID == subFolder.SubFolderID).ToList().ForEach(e =>
                        {
                            e.TotalSize += fileSize;
                            e.FileCount += fileCount;
                            e.ModifyDate = subFolder.ModifyDate;
                        });
                        context.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                if (subFolder.LevelID > 1)
                    AddToAllSubFolder(GetSubFolderById(int.Parse(subFolder.FolderID.ToString()), dbName), fileSize, fileCount, dbName);
                else
                    AddToMainFolder(subFolder.FolderID.Value, fileSize, fileCount, dbName, false, int.Parse(subFolder.PeerId.ToString()));
            }
            return status;
        }
```

Comment: Can you post your code here that does this logic? Because without code it hard to say anything

Comment: "quick solution from you geeks"? And no answer yet? But why?!

Comment: "i need a quick solution from you geeks" --> really? Hum... no.

Comment: @zeeshan Chaudhary : please provide the code so that any of us can help you out.

Comment: it might be something in the code

Comment: Yes here is the code of the recursive method

Comment: Sorry for the trouble. I am new here. Any ideas about the question?

Comment: 1) Start by removing those `catch (Exception ex) { }`, they only help to hide errors.

Comment: 2) there is no reason for recursion here, you can change it to a while loop.

Comment: 3) This should work on a single thread but with multiple you will have a db concurrency problem. Which one depends on your model and is reported in the error you kill, see 1)

Comment: Actually the exceptions catch (Exception ex) { }, are not being ingnored by me. There is some code which is handling the exceptions but i did not add it here to be precise with the problem.

Comment: Also i can use "while" here as well but currently looking to find out the problem. Also regarding the exception, i did not get any from the above code.

Comment: Also i am using the entityframework code first pattern here.

Comment: What remains is that you cannot update db fields (`e.TotalSize += ...`) like this. You would need proper concurrency handling (with `[ConcurrencyCheck]`). Probably not worth it, forget the threading.

Comment: A stab in the dark here. Is it possible that those 8 missing files are in the main folder? Or perhaps their `SubFolderID` fields don't match any existing sub folder? Have you verified that your data is correct?

Comment: Thanks for positive response. Actually the ratio is not constant, some times it is 92 out of 100 and some times 96 out of 100. @HenkHolterman can you guide me with a code example?

Answer (score 0):

Anyone still curious about the answer of my question? **Here is the answer,**

You cannot prevent the concurrency to happen in multithreadded applications. Not even with concurrency checks.

There is only one solution to this problem and it is **QUE**. There must be one thread to update the records. So this can easily be handled by the **QUE**.

I used the **QUE** and it solved my problem.